# How to create pixel graphics in 3D?

Tags: 3d, rendering, graphics, godot, pixel-art

I stumbled across this game on itch.io: [Backland](https://bcubedlabs.itch.io/backland)
After trying to find information on how to accomplish the same graphics, I found this tutorial: [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8u3LEL9jzk)

**How can I accomplish this 3-dimensional, pixelated look in a game?**

***Other possibly relevant information:***
*I have been using the Godot engine, but I would appreciate information that can be used anywhere*
*I am well versed in programming, but I am new to everything else related to game development*

Comment: Where have you run into difficulty replicating this effect with the tutorials you've consulted so far?

Comment: Set up a texture and use it with bilinear filtering turned off. See https://godotengine.org/qa/24044/disabling-filter-for-non-blurry-pixel-art-not-working-in-3-0

Answer (score 4):

Some of that pixelated look might be achievable by using normal 3D rendering with low-poly models and low-resolution textures, but render to a small texture instead of the screen, then draw that texture to the screen at a larger size with nearest neighbor filtering so the pixels don't get blurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pixelate a 3D game smoothly, I suggest checking [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-create-3d-pixel-art.1507859/) on Unity forum I wrote about creating 3D pixel art games.

I know you use Godot engine and that's on Unity forum, but the idea is the same. Basically you render the game on lower resolution (your target pixel art resolution) and upscale it back to native resolution (screen resolution). Then make some calculations so that the pixel art pixels behave smoothly. Hopefully it helps you. I'm also happy to help if you have specific questions.